# vendor/@angular/router-deprecated 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

I did not have `angualr/router-deprecated` in my angualar2 app, so i have installed it with:

```
 npm i @angular/router-deprecated
```

I have chekced the `node-module` folder and i have it there right now, and i can simply do

```
import {RouteParams} from '@angular/router-deprecated' without any error.
```

Unfortunately, in the run time my application complains with:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:4200/vendor/@angular/router-deprecated 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems that, the app expects to find `router-deprecated` in the **vendor** folder.

Meanwhile it is in node_module, so what should i do?

Here is system.config.ts:

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

When i manually update the barrels with:

```
'@angular/router-deprecated',
```

The app complains with:

```
No provider for RouteParams!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
```

Comment: add this line  'angular/router-deprecated' in barrels array

Comment: it still complains with new error

Comment: what version of angular 2 u are using RC4 or RC5 and also post the version of router as well

Comment: I think ROUTER_PROVIDERS should only be added to bootstrap(AppComponent, [...]) otherwise you'd get new instances of all providers listed in ROUTER_PROVIDERS for every component but only the shared ones contain the data you'd probably want to access. for more clarification recheck your routing settings